# Histogram from a list of matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms

I have a list of around 100 matrices, that looks like this

```
A={{{425060., 2.14235*10^6, 0.49, 0.01, 0.38, 0.620161, 
   20.}, {1.24808*10^6, 1.53025*10^6, 0.04, 0.07, 0.31, 0.320312, 
   20.}, {7.39304*10^6, 1.40204*10^6, 0.83, 0.45, 0.09, 0.94842, 20.} .... {4.27537*10^6, 
 1.62124*10^6, 0.24, 0.28, 0.62, 0.721388, 20.1}, {3.27776*10^6, 
 2.25816*10^6, 0.01, 0.21, 0.72, 0.750067, 20.1}, {3.0814*10^6, 
 1.95624*10^6, 0.02, 0.19, 0.72, 0.744916, 20.1}, {2.42706*10^6, 
 1.25729*10^6, 0.03, 0.17, 0.7, 0.720972, 20.1}, {4.47196*10^6, 
 1.23247*10^6, 0.24, 0.27, 0.57, 0.674833, 20.1}, {1.57132*10^7, 
 1.65019*10^6, 0.76, 0.92, 0.5, 1.29383, 20.1} ......
```

Each matrix has an unknown number of rows. I want to make a frequency histogram, where the frequency is the number of rows in a matrix and the bin value is the last element of each row. So eg: the first matrix has 50 rows, and the last element of each row is 20.0, so the frequency is 50 for the value 20, and so on.

Comment: Why not `Histogram[Last /@ A]`?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work for a list of matrices.

Comment: For a list of matrices `Histogram[A[[All, All, -1]]]` should work.

Comment: That works! thank you. :)

Comment: Nilanjan, great... just posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Histogram[A[[All, All, -1]]]
```